# Conditional Stored Procedure to edit specific records

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Hi and thanks in advance for your help

I am struggling to write a stored procedure in sql server to manipulate some records which are batch imported from a csv file without any particular order.

Each record represents an appointment: an entry datetime, an exit datetime and an operator ID to keep track of who did each appointment. Every appointment is 1hr in duration maximum, so moving records ahead sequentially by one hour will do the trick, I just need to have 0 overlapping minutes.

| Primary ID | Entry | Exit | Operator ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2000 07:00:00 | 01/02/2000 07:45:00 | 750 |
| 2 | 02/02/2000 07:00:00 | 02/02/2000 07:45:00 | 751 |
| 3 | 01/02/2000 07:00:00 | 01/02/2000 07:45:00 | 750 |
| 4 | 01/02/2000 07:00:00 | 01/02/2000 07:45:00 | 752 |
| 5 | 02/02/2000 07:00:00 | 02/02/2000 07:45:00 | 751 |
| 6 | 02/02/2000 07:00:00 | 02/02/2000 07:45:00 | 751 |
| 7 | 01/02/2000 07:00:00 | 01/02/2000 07:45:00 | 750 |

My problem is that when imported all appointments are all fixed at 7.00am and I can't change that.

What I am trying to achieve is to shift by one hour overlapping dates for each operator, like this:

| Primary ID | Entry | Exit | Operator ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 02/02/2000 07:00:00 | 02/02/2000 07:45:00 | 751 |
| 5 | 02/02/2000 08:00:00 | 02/02/2000 08:45:00 | 751 |
| 6 | 02/02/2000 09:00:00 | 02/02/2000 09:45:00 | 751 |

Of course I have to do this check for each operator, most importantly without jamming the server with these queries.

What must not change is the duration of the appointment (exit - entry), so that I can feed this data to another stored procedure I have already in use that will count the miinutes worked for every operator.

I look forward to reading any idea that might help me get out of this dead end.

Thank you

Comment: Let's start with assumptions. is EVERY appointment 45 minutes in duration? Or do you want to simply start every appointment on the hour (starting with 7:00 am) sequentially (and ignoring the 45 minute duration in the source)? And while you think, transforming data that you load is a serious continuity, validity, auditing issue. Seems a [tally table](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) is part of a solution here.

Comment: - every appointment is equal to or less than an hour in duration (0:30 - 0:45 - 1:00 max)
- it's perfect to have every appointment start on the hour ignoring if both in & out times are modified accordingly (duration must not be altered)
- these data are made to be modified, so no problem in writing the times we want. The goal is to use another stored procedure I have to sum up all the minutes worked by every operator. Thanks for the link to tally tables, i'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

So if we ignore the issue of more than 17 (24 - 7) appointments for a given operator in a given date, we can use something like:

```
with cte as (
    select *, 
    cast(entrytm as date) as entrydate, 
    row_number() over (partition by operatorid, cast(entrytm as date) order by primaryid) as rno
    from load)
select *, dateadd(hour, (rno - 1), entrytm) as newtm 
from cte 
order by operatorid, entrydate, rno
;
```

The fiddle code is a bit messy since I simply adapted a script that I often use as a starting point. Notice that I both pruned your sample data and added some additional rows for a better test. YOU should take that responsibility when posting a question by providing consumable data as that will encourage others to help.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=470896c079052a6b5cac42bfe43a5d1b) to demonstrate. The tally table is not needed in this case but the concept has many uses and is good to understand and learn.

Comment: I will add that this logic assumes the time portion of the entrydate value is always 7:00 am. Should there be any deviation, this will not meet your goal. It would be a good idea to validate that assumption - perhaps throw an error when it does occur!